# Cohen Forcing in Set Theory - Proof that Forcing is Equivalent to intersection of Dense Sets

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Cohen's book "Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis" on Page 126/127 (see below) shows that the existence of a completed new set a' is equivalent to its  intersection with all dense subsets in M. I have the following  questions :

(i) Is it possible to expand out the proof of the THEOREM into more detailed clear steps

and

(ii) Why in the Proof below is the set B "of forcing conditions that force either the statement or its negation" an element of M? Also how does the set of all these B i.e. {B : each element of B forces the same statement in the language} differ from the set of all dense sets ?

*********** Extract from Cohen p126/127 *************

We close with a theorem that restates the defining property of a complete sequence without using the notion of forcing. Even if we had defined complete sequences in this way, however, to show that N is a model we would still have to go through the same steps.

Definition. Let A be the set of all pairs   where P and Q are disjoint finite subsets of ω.  We write <P1,Q1> < <P2,Q2>  if P1 ⊆ P2, Q1 ⊆ Q2. A subset B of A is called dense if i) for all x ∈ A,  ∃y ∈ B and x < y, ii) x ∈ B, x < y implies y ∈ B. If {Pn} is an increasing sequence of forcing conditions, write a' = Lim Pn  if  a' = {n | ∃k (n ∈ a) ∈ Pk}.

THEOREM. If a' ⊆ ω,  ∃ a complete sequence {Pn} with a' = Lim Pn if and only if for every dense subset B of A lying in M, ∃n such that if P = a' ∩ {0,...,n} and Q = {0,...,n} - P, then <P,Q> ∈ B.

Proof. Since whether {Pn} is a complete sequence depends only on Lim Pn, the theorem gives a characterization of complete sequences. It is clear from the definition of a dense set that if B is given then for any P, ∃ Q ⊇ P such that Q forces a' to have the property of the theorem. This implies that if {Pn} is complete a' has that property. Conversely, if a' satisfies our property let Pn be any sequence with a' = Lim Pn.  Then, for any given statement let B be the set (which is in M) of forcing conditions which force either the statement or its negation. This is a dense set and hence by our condition some Pn forces either the statement or its negation.

Comment: Have you tried other, perhaps newer, sources for learning about forcing and the related basic theorems?

Comment: Asaf, thanks and I checked Kunen (10th Edition), Combinatorial Set Theory by Halbeisen (2011). However I am still unclear on the purpose of dense sets in P in the ground model M. They appear to have a dual role - linked in some way to the Boolean truth of a p-name - as well as to the creation of G by intersection (G is a' in Cohen terminology above). The set of forcing conditions that force an expression or its negation is a dense set. So intersecting all dense sets looks to determine truth of all the p-names, as well as maximally filling G to make it not a subset in P in the ground model M ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 7 years later I think I have cracked it:

The question's THEOREM is the origin of current methods of Forcing (a' $ \subseteq \omega$ is the forced new set, with dense defined as above - note its different from the current usual definition):

[  $\exists$ a negation complete sequence {$P_n$} with a' = Lim $P_n$  ] $\tag{1}$

**if and only if**

[  for every dense subset B of A lying in M, $\exists$ n such that if P = a' $\cap$ {0,...,n} and Q = {0,...,n} - P, then <P,Q> $\in$ B  ]. $\tag{2}$

Cohen's objective is "Since whether {$P_n$} is a complete sequence depends only on Lim $P_n$, the theorem gives a characterization of complete sequences [independently of the particular {$P_n$} that produce a']". Indeed as a given a' could be generated in many ways, it would be very awkward if only particular {$P_n$} could be used to create a'. So the purpose of the theorem is to show that just (2) is needed to specify a negation complete a', but it is equivalent to (1) created using the Forcing concept.

**Background to equation (1) :** A little background is needed to show how (1) is constructed. There are just three properties that Forcing needs to have to create a consistent negation complete sequence a' (with $R \in A$):

Property 1 :  $\forall  R$ $\forall \varphi$ (we do not have $ R \Vdash \varphi$ AND $ R \Vdash \neg \varphi)$

Property 2 : $\forall  R$ $\forall \varphi \text{  }  (R \Vdash \varphi$ and $S \supseteq R$ then $S \Vdash \varphi)$

Property 3 : $ \forall R \text{  } \forall \varphi \text{  } (\exists \text{  } S \supseteq R$ : either $S \Vdash \varphi$ or $S \Vdash \neg \varphi \text{ but not both })$

Note that these properties are shared by the usual $\vdash$ (if it is associated with a consistent negation complete theory), so they are the 'typical' properties required by a negation complete and consistent deductive system, based upon the usual properties of $\vdash$.

**Definition** : Let A be the set of all pairs <P,Q>, where P and Q are disjoint finite subsets of $\omega$. We write

[ $<P_1,Q_1> \text{  } \leq \text{  } <P_2,Q_2>$ ] **iff** [ $P_1 \subseteq P_2 \text{ and } Q_1 \subseteq Q_2$].

If we wish to just use a' independently of the particular {$P_n$}, the above properties need to be represented as sets. As Property 1 can be derived from the other properties, then Properties 2 and 3 need to be used in set form.

**Definition** : A Dense set B : $ B \subseteq A$ has the following two properties :

(i) Based upon Property 3, [$\forall x \in A \text{  } \exists y \in B : x \leq y$]

(ii) Based upon Property 2, [$ \forall x \text{  } \forall y \text{  }  (y \in B \text{ and } x \in A \text{ and } (x \geq y)) \text{  } \implies x \in B $]

Note that (i) & (ii) have effectively fixed $\varphi$ from Properties 3 & 2, and generalised B from relating to a particular $\varphi$, by removing $\Vdash \varphi$ from the definition of B. The approach is to ensure that the Dense sets are in M, but do not have any explicit reference to $\Vdash$ and a', since the intention is that a' is not in M. Since the B are not defined in terms of just $\varphi$, the objective is for a' to intersect all B, to ensure a complete set of $\varphi$ is captured. This intersection can't be done in the base model M, as otherwise it would define a Truth function within M contrary to the Tarski Truth definability theorem.

**Definition** : We write a' = Lim $P_n$ iff {$P_n$} is any increasing sequence of forcing conditions and a' = {n | $\exists$ k (n $\in $ a) $\in $ $P_k$}. So this extracts a' from the {$P_n$} used to construct it.

**Background to equation (2) :** To see what equation (2) is doing, we need to unpack the meaning of [$\exists$ n such that if P = a' $\cap$ {0,...,n} and Q = {0,...,n} - P, then <P,Q> $\in$ B]. Since the objective is to use a' and not specific {$P_n$}, we need a type of <P,Q> that is in any B and works just with a'. So if a' is ordered in $\omega$ so that it is an increasing set of elements of $\omega$, for finite n $\in \omega$ then  {$x : x \in a' \land  x \leq n$} will be the elements of {0..n} in a', i.e. its equal to P = a' $\cap$ {0,...,n}. Similarly for those elements not in a' but $\leq n$, Q={0..n} - P.  So the question is can such a <P,Q> be found in any dense set B, for some n ? Remarkably it can.

**Proof Equation (1) implies Equation (2) :**

Since B is dense, for any x $\in$ A, there exists a $y \geq x$ : $y \in B$. Due to (ii) B also contains all supersets of y. From Equation (1) & Property 3, for any fixed $\varphi$ there exists an $S \in A : S \supseteq$ y that gives $S \Vdash \varphi \text{ or } S \Vdash \neg \varphi$. As B is dense it contains all supersets of y, so includes S. If S = <P,Q> then the maximum n in P or Q can be found. As B is dense, it contains all supersets of S. Although B does not know a', or the elements from 0..n that are in a', since every superset of S is produced, one of them S' = <P',Q'> will only include exactly which elements of a' $\leq$ n are in a'. Hence (2) applies.

**Proof Equation (2) implies Equation (1) :**

Although the definition of a dense set dropped the reference to $\varphi$ and $\Vdash$, in fact if ALL B $\in$ M are considered (as $\Vdash$ is absolute and definable in a base countable model M of ZFC) then there will be, for each $\varphi_i$ one $B_i$ that includes **only** those b : $b \Vdash \varphi$ (or $b_i \Vdash \neg \varphi$). Let {$P_n$} be **any** set that generates a'. We know that $B_i$ will include a <P,Q> that just includes the [0..r] elements in a'. Even though <P,Q> may not be in {$P_n$} used to create a', we know as the $P_n$ are finite, whatever the {$P_n$}, there will be a first one $P_k$ that first fully describes what elements from a' are in the first [0..r] elements from $\omega$, but may of course also describe elements from a' that are greater than r. However this doesn't matter since $B_i$ is dense then it will include all supersets of <P,Q>, which will therefore include the $P_k$ $\in$ {$P_n$}. So there will be some $P_k$ that forces $\varphi$ (or $\neg \varphi$) in $B_i$. Since all $B_i$ and therefore $\varphi_i$ are in the set of all dense B, then the sequence {$P_n$} will be complete. Hence (1) applies.

**Note 1 :**

To illustrate that Properties 1, 2 & 3 arise naturally using $\vdash$ :

Property 1 : $\vdash$ is consistent :  (we do not have $ P \vdash \varphi$ AND $ P \vdash \neg \varphi)$

Property 2 : $P \vdash \varphi \text{ implies } P \land Q \vdash \varphi$

Property 3 : If $\vdash$ is associated with some axioms that make the theory T negation complete (suppressing mention of T):

Assume for each $\varphi$, $\exists \; B$ ($B \vdash \varphi$ or $B \vdash \neg \varphi$)

Then for any C, $\exists \; Q = B \land C \; $ : ($Q \vdash \varphi$ or $Q \vdash \neg \varphi$)

Hence $\forall \varphi \; \forall C$ ($\exists \; Q = B \land C$ : $Q \vdash \varphi$ or $Q \vdash \neg \varphi)$

Comment: I don’t know any of the set theory but +1 for being so dedicated as to post an answer 7 years later!

Comment: As it currently stands, Note 2, Part 1 isn't complete because it doesn't show " forcing iff intersection of dense sets". To do this with partial orders where the elements contents are assumed to not be used, it looks like it needs an extra property to do this in general (which may be the Filter property $\forall a,b \in G, \exists r \in G : (r \leq a \land r \leq a)$.

Comment: Note 2 deleted as its not directly related to the question and its only a partial answer - interesting things happen when the contents of the elements of the Poset are not used - the new set needs to effectively contain multiple linearly ordered sets.